# Javascript dictionary keys not updating, if used from array element

Tags: javascript

Can someone please help me with this?

```
let keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let data = [1, 2, 3];
let temp = [];
for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
  let key = keys[i];
temp.push({key: data[i]});
}
console.log(temp);
```

Output:

```
[ { key: 1 }, { key: 2 }, { key: 3 } ]
```

Expected OutPut:

```
[ { 'a': 1 }, { 'b': 2 }, { 'c': 3 } ]
```

Comment: What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: try this temp.push({[key]: data[i]});

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
let keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let data = [1, 2, 3];

result = keys.map((val,i)=>({[val]:data[i]}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add this change to your code if I understand your question

```
let keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let data = [1, 2, 3];
let temp = [];
for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
  let key = keys[i];
temp.push({[key]: data[i]});
}
console.log(temp);
```

If you need your key to be dynamic you need to use it the way described as above. Otherwise you've just created objects with a property named 'key'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, It will work

```js
let keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let data = [1, 2, 3];
let temp = [];
for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
  let key = keys[i];
temp.push({[key]: data[i]}); // small changes on this line
}
console.log(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let data = [1, 2, 3];
let temp = [];
for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
  let key = keys[i];

temp.push({[key]: data[i]});
}
console.log(temp);
```

use [ ] around 'key'